# Python: logging.basicConfig has no effect

Tags: python, logging

My file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
print("START")
logging.debug("DEBUG")
logging.info("INFO")
logging.warning("WARNING")
logging.error("ERROR")
logging.critical("CRITICAL")
print("END")
```

The output:

```
START
WARNING:root:WARNING
ERROR:root:ERROR
CRITICAL:root:CRITICAL
END
```

I can change the level, specify a format or a filename, all has no effect.
When I run this code with Python2, all works as expected. It also works on different systems. I think it used to work on my system too.

It seems like there is some log configuration, but I can't find it. The script is in an empty directory. There are no suspicious environment variables. Is there any other location for logging configuration or can there be any other reason for this behavior?

To be clear: The code above is the complete content of the file. I call it via `/usr/bin/python3.8 test.py` and get the mentioned output. The same, when I do it by REPL.

Comment: Try `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, force=True)`. If that works you have prove that something is already adding a logger earlier in the code.

Comment: Are you directly calling this script or importing it somewhere?

Comment: force=True works, but there is no earlier code. I call this file directly from the shell.

Comment: Despite your claim I would say it's most likely there is some code running earlier. Specifically if there is ever a call to `logging.[log|debug|info...]` that will implicitly call basicConfig and set the level to the default warn, which is what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Try This out,

```
import logging

# Logger
logger = logging.getLogger('Logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler("Logger")
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(funcName)s | PID:%(process)d | %(levelname)s | %(message)s',
                              datefmt='%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

#Logger


print("START")
logger.debug("DEBUG")
logger.info("INFO")
logger.warning("WARNING")
logger.error("ERROR")
logger.critical("CRITICAL")
print("END")
```

Comment: Also no effect. But when I change line 4 to `logger = logging.getLogger('')` it works. But now, I get every log output twice.

Comment: Can you paste the output here?

Comment: START
DEBUG:root:DEBUG
20191127-11:43:01 | <module> | PID:18289 | DEBUG | DEBUG
INFO:root:INFO
20191127-11:43:01 | <module> | PID:18289 | INFO | INFO
WARNING:root:WARNING
20191127-11:43:01 | <module> | PID:18289 | WARNING | WARNING
ERROR:root:ERROR
20191127-11:43:01 | <module> | PID:18289 | ERROR | ERROR
CRITICAL:root:CRITICAL
20191127-11:43:01 | <module> | PID:18289 | CRITICAL | CRITICAL
END